# How does JPMS knows which packages belong to which modules?

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to get a better understanding of how the new java module system works, especially when it comes to bundling together java packages to their respective modules.

I could not find a way of asking this question in an easy to understand way without tying it to a specific example.

If I have the following project structure:

```
.
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            ├── module-info.java
            └── org
                └── lb
                    └── app
                        └── App.java
```

where `module-info.java` is:

```
module lb.module {}
```

and `App.java` is:

```
package org.lb.app;

public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

and then I run the command from the `.` directory:

```
javac -d build/classes $(find src/main/ -name "*.java")
```

which gives me the following result:

```
.
├── build
│   └── classes
│       ├── module-info.class
│       └── org
│           └── lb
│               └── app
│                   └── App.class
└── src
    └── ...
```

and finally I run the command:

```
java --module-path build/classes/ --module lb.module/org.lb.app.App
```

My questions are:

1. How does the `javac` tool knows that `module-info.class` should be in the root directory folder `build/classes` if there is no "package information" (e.g. like there are in normal java files), and not, for instance in a folder that mimics the original location (e.g. `build/classes/src/main/java/module-info.class`
2. I did not expect it to work, but it does. How does the JVM knows that the `org.lb.app` package belongs to the `lb.module` module? I purposefully "misnamed" the module, making it not have same name as the directory that contains it, and also did not `export` the package. It seems obvious for a human reader, but I want to understand what the `java` program assumes in order to bundle these two together.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. It places the compiles classes in the same directory structure as they follow relative to the project structure. (package names realized as folders). 2. What if you just execute `java --module-path build/classes/ --module lb.module`(*Specifies the name of the initial module to resolve and, if it isn’t specified by the module, then specifies the name of the mainclass to execute*)?

Comment: See also JEP 261 where it describes an exploded-module directory.

Comment: Worth noting for the compiler part: per JLS §7.3 "the host system" can freely choose which module a given compilation unit (.java file) should be associated to. Hence, compilers, build tools and IDEs may support different directory layouts for the source code of modules.